# Getting Properties value for maven Pom.xml file like ant

Tags: java, xml, maven, ant

Currently I am using Ant, in which I am able to define properties file:

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
  <property file="build.properties"/> 
  <target name="info">
     <echo>Apache Ant version is ${ant.version} - You are at ${sitename} </echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I do this in maven ?
2. How can I get env information value through pom file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven properties are value placeholder, like properties in Ant. Their values are accessible anywhere within a POM by using the notation ${X}, where X is the property.

They come in five different styles:

1. Prefixing a variable with "env." will return the shell's environment variable. For example, ${env.PATH} contains the PATH environment variable.
2. A dot (.) notated path in the POM will contain the corresponding element's value. For example: 1.0 is accessible via ${project.version}
3. A dot (.) notated path in the settings.xml will contain the corresponding element's value. For example: false is accessible via ${settings.offline}.
4. Java System Properties: All properties accessible via java.lang.System.getProperties() are available as POM properties, such as ${java.home
5. Set within a  element in the POM. The value of value may be used as ${someVar}

Comment: Also for using properties file in Maven POM.xml you can use "Properties Maven Plugin" http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/